# Flutter: SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile"

Tags: flutter, gradle, build

I am getting this error while I am building APK.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile".

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           23.6s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: are you building apk in release mode  ? if yes have  you add `key.properties` file ? and add all require configuration. you can read flutter official docs to build release apk https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the `build.gradle` file used, at least post the `SigningConfig` section as based on the error message this is the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering is related to the Android Gradle build process. It indicates that there's a problem with the signing configuration for your Android application's release build.

In Android, when you build a release version of your app, you're required to sign it with a keystore file. This keystore file contains cryptographic keys used to sign your app. The error message is telling you that the necessary information to sign your app is missing.

Here's how you can fix this issue:

Create a Keystore File:

If you haven't already, you need to create a keystore file. You can do this using the keytool command-line tool that comes with the Java Development Kit (JDK). Here's an example command to generate a keystore:

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

Add Keystore Information to Your Project:

Open your project in Android Studio.
Navigate to the build.gradle file (usually located in the app module).
Ensure you have a signingConfigs block defined in your build.gradle file. It should look something like this:

android {
...
signingConfigs {
release {
storeFile file('my-release-key.keystore')
storePassword 'password'
keyAlias 'alias_name'
keyPassword 'password'
}
}
buildTypes {
release {
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
...
}
}
}

Ensure the Keystore File is in the Right Location:

Make sure that the keystore file (in this example, my-release-key.keystore) is located in the root directory of your project or specify the correct path.
Rebuild Your Project:

After making these changes, try rebuilding your project. The error should be resolved.
Remember to keep your keystore file secure and backed up, as it's crucial for releasing updates to your app on the Google Play Store.

If you're working with a team or using version control, make sure to handle the keystore file securely and consider not checking it into version control to avoid security risks. Instead, share it with team members in a secure manner.